# Why the check box in simple_form view always returns 1 when being checked or unchecked in rails 3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

A `checkbox` (need_delivery) is used to dictate if next 2 text boxes are showing or not. Those 2 text boxes are wrapped in div with id `task_request_delivery`. Here is the code in simple_form view `task_request`:

```
  <%= f.input :need_delivery, :label => 'Need Delivery：', :as => :boolean %>

  <div id="task_request_delivery">
  <%= f.input :what_to_deliver, :label => 'Content:', :input_html => {:rows => 4} %>
  <%= f.input :delivery_instruction, :label => 'Instruction:', :input_html => {:rows => 4} %>
  </div>
```

The corresponding js code under javascript is:

```
$(function(){
   $("#task_request_need_delivery").change(function() {
     var rpt = $('#task_request_need_delivery').val();
     alert(rpt);
     if ( rpt == 1 || rpt == 'true' || rpt == '1') {
        $("#task_request_delivery").show(); 
     } else {
        $("#task_request_delivery").hide(); 
     }
   }); 
});
```

The `alert(rpt)` is inserted to display the value of `rpt`. Here is what we found:

1. the value of `rpt` is always 1 when checking or unchecking the checkbox.
2. `if ( rpt == 1 || rpt == 'true' || rpt == '1')` always returns false

After checking the box initially, the 2 text boxes get hidden. After that, unchecking or checking the box did not change anything on the view (2 text boxes still hidden). Also  the `rpt` is always `1` and `if ( rpt == 1 || rpt == 'true' || rpt == '1')` is always evaluated as `false` and this is contradictory (`rpt` is 1 and then, `if` should be true). What's wrong with the code above? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `.is(':checked')` method to ensure that your checkbox is checked or not.